# Quick Action for LightningWebComponent not Possible for Task SObject

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I want to create a quick action of type LightningWebComponent for SObject **Task**. However, when I deploy the quick action I run into error: **Lightning Web Component quick actions are not supported for this entity**.

This seems strange to me, whereas it was possible for quick actions of type LightningComponent.

Does anyone know more about this or has documentation on what standard objects are supported for quick actions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.actions_overview_object_specific.htm&type=5).

> You can create object-specific actions on many objects, including:
>
> - Account
> - Campaign
> - Case
> - Contact
> - ContentNote
> - Custom objects
> - Group
> - Lead
> - Opportunity

Comment: Thanks again @sfdcfox :).